# Rails ActiveRecord shovel operator (<<) Update doesn't succeed without exception in the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

My data model has Meetings that may have Attachments. My update_meeting API has the following lines (among others):

```
attachment = Attachment.new(image: params[:attachment], user: current_user)
begin
  attachment.save!
  @meeting.attachments << attachment
  NotificationManager.add_attachment_to_meeting(current_user, @meeting, attachment)
rescue
  puts "Error occured trying to upload attachment: #{attachment.inspect}, #{attachment.errors.inspect}"
end
```

We experienced a special case where an Attachment got created but is not associated with a meeting in the database. I started to dig into the logs to find out what happened. I can't see any errors, exceptions, rollbacks, anything like that. Particularly these 3 lines are there:

```
(0.7ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "attachments" SET "updated_at" = $1, "meeting_id" = $2 WHERE "attachments"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2018-07-06 13:57:52 UTC], ["meeting_id", 434], ["id", 51]]
(1.3ms)  COMMIT
```

My assumption (prior to seeing this) would have been that if there is an UPDATE statement followed by a COMMIT without a ROLLBACK or error message or anything in the log that it should have succeeded. But apparently not.

Does anybody have any pointers where this could have gone wrong? I'm completely out of ideas on where to start looking now. Not sure how to reproduce, not sure what log messages to add to make it easier the next time it happens, not sure...

I'm using Rails 5 and PostgreSQL running on EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let the meeting create the attachment

```
begin
  attachment = @meeting.attachments.create(image: params[:attachment], user: current_user)
  NotificationManager.add_attachment_to_meeting(current_user, @meeting, attachment)
rescue
  puts "Error occured trying to upload attachment: #{attachment.inspect}, #{attachment.errors.inspect}"
end
```

the meeting should be like an "aggregator" for attachments. attachments should not exist or at least, do not make sense for to them exist without a meeting, so they should be created through the meeting

Comment: That sounds like a good suggestion. One question though: do you have any idea why the above case failed without any trace of an error? If above fails like that, how would your implementation behave in this case?

Comment: most probably because your method `add_attachment_to_meeting` is failing silently instead raise an exception. Anyway, the right way to do it is to create the attachment through the meeting so that you don't need to care about connecting those two

Comment: Maybe one more question, now that we're just looking at these lines of code: would you use "create" or "create!" ?

Comment: I prefer to use `create!` so Rails is very loud when something fails and I can catch the exception and deal with it properly

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected. Alright, thanks also for this!